# In spacy custom trianed model : Config Validation error ner -> incorrect_spans_key extra fields not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, nlp, spacy-3

I am running into the problem whenever I try to load custom trained NER model of spacy inside **docker container**.

**Note:**
*I am using latest spacy version 3.0 and trained that NER model using CLI commands of spacy, first by converting Train data format into .spacy format*

The error throws as following(You can check error in image as hyperlinked):

[config validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CjDl.png)

My trained model file structure looks like this:
[custom ner model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uSVx.png)

**But while run that model without docker it works perfectly**. What wrong I have done in this process. Plz help me to resolve the error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of errors or code, copy/paste the text.

Comment: I would check that you have the exact same spaCy version inside and outside of Docker. Based on your error it sounds like something in the config changed.

Comment: @polm23 Thank you for your answer. Exactly the same thing happen as you said due to the different spacy versions in development v3.1.0 and in docker v3.0.6. I used the model that was trained in specific version in docker too. And it works perfectly. Thank you once again